# How can I loop over the output of a command with an index

Tags: shell, for-loop

Basically, I want to do something like

```
foo=$(ls /)
for i in "${!foo[@]}"; echo $i foo[$i]; done
```

and print. Note that I don't really care about the index order, so any indexing will do.

```
0 file1.txt
1 file2.txt
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over **lines** in output of a command, `read` the line, line by line and keep an index. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 .

```
foo=$(a command)
i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "$i $line"
   i=$((i + 1))
done <<<"$foo"
```

If you want to loop over **files** in a directory, [do not use ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), and you should loop over the result of globulation. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 .

```
i=0
for file in /*; do
   echo "$i $file"
   i=$((i + 1))
done
```